# Javascript Infinity

Tags: javascript, infinity

Division by 0 gives this special value:

```
 3/0 output:Infinity
```

You can’t play positive and negative infinity against each other:

```
Infinity - Infinity output:NaN (Why?)
```

It also turns out that “beyond infinity” is still infinity:

```
 Infinity + Infinity output:Infinity(this is accepted)


 5 * Infinity
Infinity(this is also accepted)
```

so why infinity-infinity evalutes to NaN?It should be infinity isn't it?Also i wanted to know why cant object be converted to primitive values?Sorry for posting two question at a time ,as this is the last question i can post.See here:

```
var obj = {
    valueOf: function () {
        console.log("valueOf");
        return {}; // not a primitive
    },
    toString: function () {
        console.log("toString");
        return {}; // not a primitive
    }
}

 Number(obj) //TypeError: Cannot convert object to primitive values
```

Comment: I'd just post the second half of your question as another question (if you can't find one here).

Comment: Here is good explanation for this. 

[What is the result of infinity minus infinity?]


  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60766/what-is-the-result-of-infinity-minus-infinity

Comment: @SeanVieira Dont do that?emmm

Answer (score 9):

That's how ∞ works in mathematics. Infinity itself is not a number, it is a concept. The general idea is that
`∞ + x = ∞ ∀ x`

∞ is, obviously, infinitely big. If you subtract an infinitely big thing from another infinitely big thing, you can't define what you have left. If the first infinity is bigger, you'll get a negative result, but if it's smaller then the result will be positive (basic rule of subtraction), but since both are infinitely big you have no way of knowing which is bigger (unless more information is given, such as the context leading to these infinities*). Therefore, as far as the computer is concerned, ∞ - ∞ is mathematically undefined, or Not a Number.

* Example: Let x = the sum of all positive integers, and y = the sum of each positive integer doubled. In this case, we can say that y > x, even though both are infinity.

Comment: what about my next question

Comment: `valueOf` and `toString` MUST return a primitive. To not do so is assumed to be an error in computing the return value. Rather than taking a guess at what you meant, it throws an exception.

Comment: It's not really accurate to say that you'd get a negative or positive result if you subtract a "larger" infinity from a "smaller" infinity. For example you can't say `a = ∞; b = a + 1; b - a = 1`. Similarly the example in the end of the answer is incorrect: if x is the sum of positive integers and y is the sum of positive integers doubled, you *can't* say `y > x` because they're both "equally infinite".

Answer (score 0):

Because it's an indeterminate form, so it's not infinity. `NaN` reflects this the best way possible.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form

Related question:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60766/what-is-the-result-of-infinity-minus-infinity

Answer (score 0):

```
var A = 1/0
var B = 2 * A
var c = B - A
```

Note that even though B = 2 * A, still A = B (2 * infinity is still infinity, so they are both infinity), so what do you expect C to be? infinity or 0?

Infinity is not really a number, mathematically speaking. Though IsNaN(1/0) = false.

Comment: what about the next part of the question?

Comment: How would you want to evaluate this object to a number? Number() wasn't built for that, so it fails. You'd need to write your own function.

Comment: Technically, `B - A` can be rewritten to `2 * A - A`, which is `A` and therefore `Infinity`. Similarly, `A - B` can be rewritten as `A - (2 * A)`, which is `-A` and therefore `-Infinity`. However, I can only arrive at this result because I am handling the variables directly, which most programming languages can't do.

Comment: Actually, in the world of *mathematics* infinity is NOT a number (despite Javascript's claim) so  `A - (2 * A)`, is *not* `-A`.

Comment: `A - (2 * A) = -A ` --> there a exists a number `B = 2 * A`, such that `B > A`.  ... um, do you see the problem here? A number *greater than infinity* This proves that infinity is not a member of the set of real numbers, and you should not think of it as obeying the associative, communative, and distributive properties of the reals.